# Angular UI-Grid upward table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is the program overview. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIsDz.png)

I hope it can let the line `13 to 17` upward to column `2`, it like that 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIsDz.png) .

I hope the result is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a81e.png)

This is feasible or not?

This is my UI-grid program.

https://plnkr.co/edit/opJoT59iEPM9ojLVXvRc?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible but this is not directly ui-grid related. You have to aggregate your data correspondingly.

Right now your data are of the form:

```
{
    "SEGMENT": "AA",
    "JAN19COMM_VAL": "504000",
    "JAN19TARGET": "0",
    "JAN19ACH": "0"
},
    {
    "SEGMENT": "AA",
    "FEB19COMM_VAL": "16871",
    "FEB19TARGET": "0",
    "FEB19ACH": "0"
}
```

what you desire is something like this:

```
{
    "SEGEMNT": "AA",
    "JAN19COMM_VAL": "504000",
    "JAN19TARGET": "0",
    "JAN19ACH": "0",
    "FEB19COMM_VAL": "16871",
    "FEB19TARGET": "0",
    "FEB19ACH": "0"
}
```

You could use `Object.assign` to combine the given objects.